# PGFPlots: Can't change font size of y-axis

Tags: pgfplots, fontsize, axis

I have a problem formatting a graph I made with `pgfplots`. I can change the font size of the x-axis, but it wouldn't work with the y-axis. The font size of the y-axis wouldn't change when I change this part of the code and I don't understand why:

```
yticklabel style={
font=\tiny,
},
```

I would appreciate your help!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6,
%transform shape
]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={
font=\tiny,
%at={(0.5,-0.25)},
%anchor=north,legend columns=-1
},
ylabel={Anteil},
symbolic x coords={Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1,Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2,Treffer,Falscher Alarm},
xtick=data,
xticklabel style={text width=1.5cm,
font=\tiny,
align=center
},
yticklabel style={
font=\tiny,
},
]
%neutral
\addplot[blue,fill=blue!30!white,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,]
coordinates{(Treffer,0.8560) +-(0.01503,0.01503) (Falscher Alarm,0.1390) +-(0.01737,0.01737)(Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1,0.1481) +-(0.01067,0.01067) (Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2,0.1119) +-(0.00922,0.00922) };
%negativ
\addplot[red,fill=red!30!white,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,]
coordinates {(Treffer,0.9365) +- (0.00587,0.00587)(Falscher Alarm,0.1435) +- (0.01737,0.01737)(Freie Wiedergabe Tag 1,0.3247) +-(0.01695,0.01695) (Freie Wiedergabe Tag 2,0.2556) +-(0.01524,0.01524)
};
\legend{neutral,negativ}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Unterschrift}
\label{GedaechtnisBilder}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are talking about the `yticklabels` (the numbers), or the `ylabel` ("Anteil")? You've only changed the style of the ticklabels, `ylabel style={font=\tiny}` is needed to change the style of the axis label.

Comment: The yticklabels are pretty tiny with your code in my environment.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you! I didn't see the obvious and confused `yticklabels` with `ylabel`. It works now with `ylabel style={font=\tiny}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: If you would like to write an answer, I could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different styles for the different axis descriptions. You have changed the style for the `yticklabels` on y-axis, i.e. the numbers, but you want to change the style for the `ylabel`. Hence, you're after

```
ylabel style={font=\tiny}
```